# Movie featuring a little girl and cyborgs, with an old -west feel

Tags: cyborg, story-identification

Back in the 90's I remember watching a late-night movie on one of the networks.

The story took place in an arid, post-apocaliptic future. The plot revolved around a little girl who befriended a cyborg killing machine. The cyborg killing machine spent the movie blasting apart a gang of evil cyborgs to protect her, and it seems like he died in the end.

It had an old west or samurai vibe to it, and it seemed pretty good for the timeslot it was in. Any ideas what this film might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S. Albano, in case you haven't already found the movie, the one you're looking for is [Knights (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107333/)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_(film)):

> The cyborg Gabriel was created to destroy all other cyborgs. He later rescues Nea by killing the cyborg Simon. Gabriel trains Nea to become a cyborg killer and help him. They continue to kill cyborgs until Gabriel is torn in half by one of his targets and taken to the cyborg camp. Nea follows Jacob and challenges the cyborg leader Job to a fight. Finding Gabriel, she straps him to her back and they battle cyborgs until Gabriel can attach a dead cyborg's legs to himself. They pursue Job, but before they can catch him, the Master Builder captures Nea's brother, taking him to Cyborg City. During a battle, Job tells Gabriel that the cyborg population can't be stopped. Job dies moments later. Gabriel and Nea ride off in search of her brother.

**Trailer**

Comment: Or I could be wrong - because in Knights the girl isn't so little and she blasts the cyborgs herslef!

Comment: Nope, that is totally the movie :)

Answer (score 6):

Is it by any chance [Screamers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/)?

The main character is a human soldier (or mercenary, can't remember exactly). He travels trough an arid, desolated post-apocalyptic planet and saves a little girl from cyborg killing machines, and she follows him 'till the end of the movie, when he dies.

Comment: Hard to say. It does sound quite a bit like it, but there was no company that created the cyborgs to negotiate with in the movie. The gang of cyborgs also did not scream. I will look into it though, because I could just mis-remember the details.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be the film [Cyborg](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097138/).

> Gibson Rickenbacker is a hired fighter living in a plague-ravaged apocalyptic America where a plague has infested most of the United States and the rest of the world. In New York City, Gibson encounters a woman named Pearl Prophet. Pearl reveals to Gibson that she is a cyborg who is carrying vital-information for a group of scientists in Atlanta who are working on a cure to the plague and Pearl hires Gibson to escort her back to Atlanta. But Pearl is kidnapped by "Pirates" a murderous gang led by Fender Tremolo, who wants the cure for themselves and they decide to take Pearl to Atlanta themselves. Gibson, joined by a young woman named Nady Simmons, goes in pursuit of Fender and his gang, as Gibson sets out to rescue Pearl, stop Fender and his gang from reaching Atlanta and defeat Fender who slaughtered Gibson's family. (From IMDB)

Comment: I don't remember anything about a plague, but I will look into this one too. It does seem like it might have more of the cyborg motorcycle gang feel I remember.