# A movie from 2014-2016 that has robots be, spaceships and cyborg who saves a little girl and keeps her locked in his cave/house. It's dark and gloomy

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a movie with a cyborg who fixes dolls (I believe) and he saves this little girl but also keeps her captive in his dark and gloomy lair.

There are fights, bounty hunters on robots/cyborgs and slavery along with spaceships and big legged machines.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23575/movie-featuring-a-little-girl-and-cyborgs-with-an-old-west-feel  Some possible matches here

Answer (score 4):

Could be [Mortal Engines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTGdpJj0srY), but it is from 2018.

Plot

> Hundreds of years after a cataclysmic event destroyed civilization,
> mysterious young Hester Shaw emerges as the only one who can stop the
> city of London -- now a giant predator on wheels -- from devouring
> everything in its path. Feral and fiercely driven by the memory of her
> mother, Hester joins forces with Tom Natsworthy, an outcast from
> London, and Anna Fang, a dangerous outlaw with a bounty on her head.

Cyborg (Shrike) saves this girl (Hester):
[image]

Cyborg fixing dolls:
[image]
Gloomy lair:
[image]
Hester:
[image]
Machines:
[image]
Air combat scene:
[image]